# PostgresSQL создание триггера

Tags: sql, postgresql

Ребят, не могу справиться вот с такой задачей: у меня база данных сервисного центра, и необходимо создать триггер - При добавлении услуг на заказ, проверить, что деталь (запчасти) есть в наличии. Буду рад помощи. [image: Даталогическая схема]. 
То есть, при добавлении нового "заказа на ремонт" (поля idservice(код услуги)) нам необходимо выдать сообщение об ошибке, что запчастей нет в наличии. Если есть в наличии, то данные в таблицу repairorder(заказ на ремонт) должны заполняться. Что пока реализовал:

```
create function funcTrigCheck() RETURNS trigger AS '
BEGIN
  IF (select count(spares.quantity)<1 
  from spares, typesofservices, listofworks, repairorder
  where repairorder.idservice=listofworks.idservice and 
  listofworks.idservice=typesofservices.idservice and 
  typesofservices.idspares=spares.idspares) THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION ''Запчастей нет!'';
    END IF;
    return null;
End;
' language plpgsql;

create trigger t4
    before INSERT on repairorder for each row
    execute procedure funcTrigCheck();
```

Как мне организовать проверку каких-то определенных запчастей, какая ошибка в моей функции? То есть данная функция работает не корректно, count считает общее количество запчастей и выводит сообщение.

Таблица "Заказ на ремонт":

```
create table repairorder
(
idorder integer NOT NULL primary key unique,
idclients integer NOT NULL REFERENCES clients(idclients),
idequipment integer NOT NULL REFERENCES equipment(idequipment),
idstatus integer NOT NULL REFERENCES orderstatus(idstatus),
idservice integer NOT NULL REFERENCES typesofservices(idservice),
sn varchar(100),
disrepair varchar(100),
equipment varchar(100));
```

Таблица "Виды услуг":

```
create table typesofservices
(
idservice integer NOT NULL primary key unique,
idspares integer NOT NULL REFERENCES spares(idspares),
description varchar(100),
price integer
);
```

Таблица "Запчасти":

```
create table spares
(
idspares integer NOT NULL primary key unique,
name varchar(100),
quantity integer
);
```

Comment: Принцип такой... Попробуй написать SELECT (spares.idspares, SELECT COUNT( 'твой запрос')) FROM... И не забудь в подзапросе WHERE добавить еще одно условие, которое связано с id

Comment: Запрос работает так, как ты его написал.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во-первых, есть более удобный способ задать тело процедуры, чем строкой. Во-вторых, неявные объединения - это уродливое наследие стандарта SQL89. В-третьих, стоило или выложить sql-код таблиц или, хотя бы, в схеме указать реальные названия таблиц и реальные названия полей. Кроме того, отношение между таблицей услуг и таблицей запчастей выглядит как m2m, одной таблицей вы не обойдётесь. И не помешал бы пример кода вставки, на который вы хотите повесить триггер. По существу вопроса могу предположить такое решение:

```
create or replace function check_spares() returns trigger as $$
begin
    if exists (
        select
          1
        from spares as s
        inner join typesofservices as ts
          using(idspares)
        inner join listofworks as lw
          using(idservice)
        where lw.idservice = NEW.idservice
          and s.quantity > 0
    ) then
        return NEW;
    else
        raise exception 'Запчастей нет!';
    end if;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Comment: Выложил sql-код некоторых таблиц. Пытался сделать, чтобы при добавлении в поле idservice таблицы repairorder выдавало сообщение об ошибке. Спасибо за Ваш ответ!

Comment: Ответ вам помог?

Comment: Помог! Только осталось мне разобраться, когда при вашем запросе будет исключительная ситуация.

Comment: Вот добавляет, только когда вызывается исключение? Пока этого добиться не могу, уже quantity на 0 поставил.

Comment: Исправил, проверьте.

Comment: Правильно ли я делаю: создаю триггер, перед вставкой в таблицу repairorder?
create trigger check_spares
    before INSERT on repairorder for each row
    execute procedure check_spares();

Comment: Да, правильно делаете.

Answer (score 2):

У Вас идеологический косяк. Формирование заказа никак не связано с наличием для него необходимых запчастей - даже если их нет, заказ всё равно должен быть сформирован. А если будет отказ - клиент поедет на другой сервис,- то это внешнее решение, которое не контролируется на уровне БД.

Это забота клиентской части, а не базы - проверить и выдать сообщение. Соответственно именно клиентская часть должна одним запросом вставлять запись о заказе, а вторым - проверять наличие запчастей и материалов, и при их отсутствии давать сообщение. А, возможно, что и в обратном порядке - ибо результат проверки может повлиять на решение создавать или не создавать заказ.

Comment: Такую задачу мне поставили, увы, вот и приходиться выкручиваться. Но спасибо за Ваш комментарий!

Comment: Вам не только поставили задачу, но и указали путь её решения, причём безальтернативно? странно это...

Comment: Таков попался преподаватель в моём университете. Не было желания даже и принимать эту задачу. Работал бы над реальной задачей для клиента - делал бы так, как вы рекомендуете.